# How to parse this datasnapshot using Firebase and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this data structure

```
{
  "job-requests" : {
    "pending" : {
      "-KkyZGfqmiIVryyLAZpD" : {
        "job_details" : "asd",
        "job_type" : "Repair Required",
        "location" : "123",
        "location_lat" : 14.164633210106128,
        "location_lng" : 121.24110514763743,
        "timestamp" : 1495698316411
      }
    }
  },
  "office-info" : {
    "123" : {
      "office_acronym" : "123",
      "office_contact_number" : "123-1234",
      "office_current_head" : "None",
      "office_name" : "123",
      "office_parent_unit" : "123"
    }
  },
  "office-location-list" : {
    "123" : {
      "location_lat" : 14.164633210106128,
      "location_lng" : 121.24110514763743
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "MBR5o37xafUyuLw14Xqa1ku0Zui1" : {
      "designation" : "staff",
      "email" : "123@asd.com",
      "given_name" : "23",
      "last_name" : "123",
      "password" : "1234567",
      "timestamp" : 1495617328793
    },
    "Nwacy3ADczgLC85OvSAgUNEGMkx2" : {
      "designation" : "staff",
      "email" : "adsasd@asdas.com",
      "given_name" : "122123",
      "last_name" : "12",
      "password" : "asdasdsadasd",
      "timestamp" : 1495681430048
    }
  }
}
```

I will be needing the keys `[pending, active, finished]` along with the data of the newly added child. This is how I accessed Firebase

```
   firebase.database ().ref ('job-requests').on ('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    console.log (snapshot.key); // prints out [pending, active, finished]
    console.log (snapshot.val()); // prints out an object
});
```

It prints this on the console:

[image: Screenshot of console]

I tried using `JSON.parse ()`, `snapshot.child (path)`, `snapshot.field`, and `snapshot[field]` but errors are thrown out. How do I do this?

Comment: You should do `snapshot.val().field`

Comment: it returned `undefined`. @user7814783

Comment: what object do you get when you do `console.log (snapshot.val())`

Comment: [This](http://imgur.com/6SwBDbI) appears on the console. @user7814783 



EDIT: I actually had a dirty fix wherein I added multiple listeners on more specific routes.

Comment: What exact error do you get? Also: the JSON that is printed in the console does not seem to match with the diagram you shared (there is some weird nesting as far as I can see). Please share a snippet of the actual JSON. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen [Here](https://pastebin.com/HBDX1YMk) it is. I am just new to Firebase. I apologize for the crappy structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gets **all** job requests. Since those are in a hierarchy by their state, your code will need to handle this:

```
firebase.database ().ref ('job-requests').on ('child_added', (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((stateSnapshot) => {
    console.log(stateSnapshot.key); // 'pending', etc
    stateSnapshot.forEach((jobSnapshot) => {
      console.log(jobSnapshot.key);
      console.log(jobSnapshot.val());
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Oh. I really haven't gotten a grasp of Firebase yet. Thank you for this.